# How to turn off jar compression in Maven

Tags: maven-2, build, jar

Is there an option in Maven (2.0.9) to turn off jar compression for the entire operation? I'm using Maven both in the build server and in my work station and I'd like to disable jar compression on the work station builds (development only). However, I don't want to touch all the poms and create two versions for each.

Is there an option for turning off jar compression by environment variable, file or by touching a single pom.xml?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, you could define different jar plugin by profile. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Ran Biron: I'm not completely sure, but as you may know you can redefine plugins on a per profile basis. I've worked to little on multi level POM projects to have tested whether profile selection is passed in to child poms, but I can very well imagine that it may be so. I would test it myself, but it's time to leave the office =)

Comment: see my own answer for details. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Apparently it's possible by defining this:

```
 <profile><id>...</id>
   <build>
     <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <configuration>
                     <archive>
                         <compress>false</compress>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</profile>
```

in the top-level pom.xml.
As a side note - this didn't really solved my initial problem of the build taking too much time.

Comment: 1. I provided the details, the original answerer provided the idea.
2. I think it's better to give "accepted" to another person for partial idea than to myself for a full idea.

Comment: I'd suggest thinking of changing the selected answer (though it's great how you wish to share credit!). For people trying to find a working solution it's really neat to get the best answer as the "accepted" one. Now, the accepted answer does not actually answer the problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything when also using `maven-shade-plugin`. Anyone know how to disable compression there?

Answer (score 15):

Add the following to the build.plugins section in your project's pom.xml file.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <compress>false</compress>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This turns off jar file compression for your maven project.

Comment: How do you turn it off only for one artifact though?  Say a key file or something that if stored compressed won't work...

Answer (score 1):

finally I found the answer of this topic (***turn off the jar compression***), configuring directly into the pom, also I found other two interesting details: putting a ***different jar's name*** and ***includ a "manifest"*** definition. Here is my pom fragment.

```
<build>
    <finalName>***FileName***</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <!-- Set a JDK compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Make this jar executable -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                    <mainClass>***package.test.ClassTest***</mainClass>
                </manifest>
                <compress>***false***</compress>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```